# ORDER BY clause in SQL

Tags: sql

What is the meaning of `ORDER BY 1,2`

Can we use numeric values in the `ORDER BY` clause?

Is this a valid statement?

Comment: It's valid - but I'd still recommend using the **column names** instead of just their ordinal position - less chance for unexpected surprises!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ORDER BY 1, 2` will order your data by first and second expressions in your select. For example:

```
SELECT 
    Col1,
    Col2
FROM 
    Table
ORDER BY 
    1
```

is the same as:

```
SELECT 
    Col1,
    Col2
FROM 
    Table
ORDER BY 
    Col1
```

You can use this notation with expressions, for example:

```
SELECT 
    10 - IntCol1,
    Col2
FROM 
    Table
ORDER BY 
    1
```

Comment: It's the same, as long as you don't change the column list in your SELECT. If you do - you're suddenly ordering by something else entirely....

Answer (score 3):

This is a valid statement. The numbers point to the column position in your result.

```
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

is the same as

```
ORDER BY MyTable.FirstColumn, MyTable.SecondColumn
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. It is ordering by columns without specifying the column name. So ordering by 1,2 is ordering by the first column, then by the second column.

Check out this article for more info:

http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlorderby.html

Answer (score 0):

Numbers refer to the order of columns